# Zend Framework 11.1.9 action executed twice

Tags: zend-framework

I am using Zend Framework and running into issues where myAction() is called twice. After spending many hours looking for other developers with same experience it seems that there are some main issues that people have solved. Either:

-*.css / *.js file or favicon is not found, so I tailed the apache access log fiel with no thing to show for.

-Then I looked for images that did not exist that were referenced in any css. No luck there as well.

-Lastly I found that people using ZFDebug were running into issues, but since I am not using that or have it installed this is something I cannot troubleshoot.

Please if anyone has any idea of what I can try to resolve the issue I would grateful if you would share this with me.

---

**UPDATE:**

kinghfb and Phil,

Thank you very much for your replies.

Your information was very clear and all very good suggestions. I double checked all my css and js files and since I don't really use partials but have view helpers that was an easy check as well. All were at least 4k and none were empty. I also, tried what Phil suggested changed:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

to:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Which also did not solve my problem. I did fail to say earlier that when I disable layout in the action it runs only once. Any other suggestions?

Comment: How did you notice the double execution? is it processing something twice? or is it a page loading twice?

Comment: humm, i double checked my included css,ja and images. I tested the htaccess fix and i commented out the ZFdebug component but i'm still have the same double call issue. My action is calling a mysql stored procedure - any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same problem, and found solutions similar to what you describe (Zend Debug, favicon.ico etc etc). However, I wasn't running any of these things.

What you need to check is that all the requested files actually exist and are greater than 0 bytes (JS, CSS, images, and -importantly- template files), otherwise the system won't find it and try to Bootstrap the app again. This is because the default mod_rewrite settings only bypass the bootstrap when the requested file is > 0 bytes.

Hopefully that's clear and helped :)

Comment: This one used to always get me. Stupid, empty `common.css` file :). You can also change the rewrite condition from `-s` to `-f` to skip the size check.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks really much for this answer kinghfb, you saved me lots of time...

In my layout file I had 3 of those (that causes the controller to execute 3 times) :

```
<img src="path/path/file.jpg" >
```

I had to do this instead :

```
<img src="/path/path/file.jpg" >
```

The way I've found this is by writing to a file in my controller (doing only echo won't show it)

Comment: what did you write to the file to indicate that the image resources was invalid? can you post a code snippet?